# getElementbyID in PHP?

Tags: php, soap, getelementbyid

I have a site that calls a large part of it's HTML from a SOAP server that I have no access to other than to call this HTML back, preformatted.

I need to get the values of certain elements, but because it for use with the facebook open graph metatags, it can't be processed by the javascript at the client side, it needs to be caught by the server to be added to the metatags before sending it to the browser.

I am looking for a function that can help me pick out certain elements to add them to the metatags.

The CSS locations for the elements are as follows:

```
div#Description.Group div.Content p:first-child
```

&&

```
div#Heading.Group div.Content
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at XPath. It may not work it the html you get delivered is no valid XHTML though.

Comment: XPath is not Selectors. Can you please clarify how the OP can achieve the equivalent Selector with XPath? Otherwise I'd say this answer is better suited as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you can create DOM from HTML pages or using strings having HTML and then use getElementByID function like on DOM object to get that element .

For creating DOM element in PHP http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.construct.php
and check http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php  for  getelementbyid()